# Animated Header navigation shrink after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this repo for an animated header:

https://github.com/codrops/AnimatedHeader

The only problem I'm having is that it shrinks around 300pixels of scrolling where as I need it to active after scrolling at around 150px. There where two values in the js which I reduced drastically but it did not make any difference. Is anyone able to advise how can to change it please?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code it seems that this variable `changeHeaderOn = 300;` needs to be changed in order to accommodate your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaScript file cbpAnimatedHeader.js it seems that the variable changeHeaderOn sets the breakpoint for animating the header.

Make sure you change this value in the minified javascript file or change the reference in the html page to the uniminified version!

Comment: awesome thank you, my silly mistake of editing the unminified version! Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

open file **cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js**

find `a=300` and change it to `a = 150`

That's it